# OpenCV not compiled with OpenGL

Tags: opencv, opengl

I am trying to render OpenGL graphics on OpenCV video stream, but when I run my program I get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/opencv-20200909-20320-7icpjn/opencv-4.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:478: error: (-218:No OpenGL support) The library is compiled without OpenGL support in function 'cvSetOpenGlContext'
```

I am currently on a Mac and every solution I've seen is related to Linux. Any help is appreciated.